# MS Access update Value as NULL

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following code on `fieldApplicationType`

```
Private Sub fieldApplicationType_AfterUpdate()
    If (Me.fieldApplicationType.Value = 200 Or Me.fieldApplicationType.Value = 300) Then
        Me.fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want to be able to do is in the `Else` not only do I want to disable the field (which is working) I also want to set the `Value` to NULL if it isn't currently already NULL.

Doing `Me.fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction.Value = Null` is not changing anything however.  `fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction` is a ComboBox.

The `Row Source`for the ComboBox are coming from a view and `Limit To List` is Yes along with `Allow Value List Edits`

Comment: Tried this in Access 2010, it works fine. Unfortunately have no 2007 installed. How combo looks like if record has null value? Try to save form after value setting and requery

Comment: Your codes seems okay. Can you share a sample file what not working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Me.fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction.Value = Me.fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction.DefaultValue
```

That's assuming your default value is null.